# I am trying to get the sha-id of my flutter application by running ./gradlew signingReport ,

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsPpe.png)

i tried creating another application,but got the same error, i specied the signingconfigs in the gradle and i am getting this error everytime when i try to get sha id  using ./gradlew signingReport , is this some kind of bug?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.